# JOIN question for MySQL Merging Queries--Overwrite or Merge two rows from the same table

Tags: mysql, join, merge, overwrite, coalesce

It's difficult to explain this, so I'll do my best.

I have a table that consists of default rows (noted by a `NULL` `specificSiteID`) and override rows (noted by NON-`NULL` `specificSiteID`s.)

Both types of rows use `genericID` to determine the data being loaded-- sometimes, there may be no defaults for some data.

**edit 1:** The Non-null `specificSiteID`s I refer to only override a default when their siteID matches the one I am querying for.  I don't apply all overrides to one default-- I only apply a `specificSiteID`'s override to the default.
**end edit 1**

I have four requirements of this query:

1. Return no data when there is neither a default nor a line-specific override.
2. Return the override data when there is no default data
3. Return the Override data overwriting the default data where the override data is not null
4. and finally, Return only the default data when it exists and there is no override data.

Right now, my SQL Query looks like--

```
SELECT COALESCE( override.Col1 , default.Col1) as Col1,
 COALESCE(override.Col2, default.Col2) as Col2
 FROM
  (SELECT * from tableA where 
     genericID = 84 AND 
     specificSiteID IS NULL ) as default
 LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT * from tableA where 
     genericID = 84 AND 
     specificSiteID = 34 ) as override
 ON default.genericID = override.genericID;
```

The problem with this script is that case #2 fails due to the `LEFT JOIN`.  **When there's no default row to `LEFT JOIN` upon, the override row isn't included.**  Using the above example, if there is no `genericID` = 84 where `specificSiteID` is `NULL`, no data is returned, even if there is override data.

What kind of `JOIN` am I looking for?  Can I even cover this with a `JOIN`?

Comment: At this point, I've decided to handle the data coalescence in the programming and not on the DB end.

Answer (score 1):

As Mysql doesn't support the full join, but you can simulate it using "left join" + "right join".

I think that the genericID 34 and the specificSiteID 84 are examples, and you need the join of all  genericIDs where the specificSiteId is null (default) and is not null (override), don't you?

```
SELECT COALESCE( override.Col1 , default.Col1) as Col1,
       COALESCE(override.Col2, default.Col2) as Col2
  FROM (SELECT * from tableA where specificSiteID IS NULL ) as default
        LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * from tableA where specificSiteID is not null ) as override
               ON default.genericID = override.genericID
UNION 
SELECT COALESCE( override.Col1 , default.Col1) as Col1,
       COALESCE(override.Col2, default.Col2) as Col2
  FROM (SELECT * from tableA where specificSiteID IS NULL ) as default
        RIGHT JOIN  (SELECT * from tableA where specificSiteID is not null ) as override
               ON default.genericID = override.genericID
```

But looking this query seems that your DB design is not the more appropriate for your case

Comment: To answer your question:   I only need to join a row matching the `genericID` and a null `specificSiteID` WITH a row matching the `genericID` and a `specificSiteID` matching the provided ID.  EG:  If I have a specificSiteID of 86 in my example, I would only collect two rows at most, not a multitude.    **Next**:  I then looked at the code you provided to see if it applied, but maybe I erred in my initial explanation.  I'll try editing it. :)  (Thanks for the +1, btw!)